# Web UI Library that already handles styling for the following elements?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frameworks, ria

I'm having trouble finding a simple js web UI library that handles styling the following right out of the box:

- Buttons
- Listboxes
- Input Boxes
- Dropdown Menus
- Text Areas
- Checkboxes
- Radio Buttons
- Alert Dialogs
- Modal / Non-modal Windows

I can see various libraries offering styling but so far haven't found one that handles the aforementioned all at once. The reason why I'm looking for something that already contains support for all of the above in one go is because I've had previous experiences with different frameworks / libraries conflicting with each other because they weren't from the same developer / author.

So before jumping in and trying to mix and match those that I've found, I just want to make sure I haven't missed something good.

Comment: It may be hard to find a js UI library to suit all your needs... so I think it's better to focus on the conflict part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Dojo: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/themePreviewer/demo.html

All of those widgets have styling "right out of the box."  If that doesn't meet your needs, maybe you could be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello @Marc, basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to have consistent HTML elements on all-throughout my website. That means having the same style for all the buttons I use, the input boxes, etc.

Comment: Is there something about the dojo toolkit I recommended that doesn't provide that?

Comment: Actually I thin Dojo kit is the one I'm looking for, I just forgot to mark your answer. Apologies. :P